What plaster/compound to level lath wall
I have a section of century house lath strips exposed under a newly drywalled area. I need to fill up the ~3/8" thickness to make the lower section level with the upper so  I can install baseboards. Is plaster the only way? My beginner DIY brain wonders if using 1/4" drywall may be easier and quicker. Assuming this is not a bad idea, what can i use to level the 1/8" gap that will remain at the intersection between this new 1/4" drywal and the existing drywall above?



I suggest that you investigate using 3/8" thick drywall for this application. It will be much easier to tape and feather in the edges with this to the plaster than using 1/4" thick material.
Also 3/8" drywall is probably going to be more sturdy and able to bridge surface variations of the lath behind than the thinner stuff.
